# In Xcode, swift debugger always shows unresolved identifier when trying examine variables

Tags: xcode, swift, debugging

New to debugging swift in xcode - often when I try to examine variables in the debugger I get the error use of unresolved identifier when I use the po command, and I don't see the local variables in the variables window.  What am I doing wrong?

[image: Debugger Window]

Comment: It was fixed in the newest beta, but prior to that the debugger wasn't really reliable

Comment: changed to var - which didn't work.  I'll try switching to the latest beta

Comment: For the record, the debugger _still_ does this crap in Xcode 10. This is maddening. :(